# Customers cannot login issue magento 1

Tags: magento-1, session

This issue is only on Chrome. I got redirected to the login page after login.
I tried the following:

**1.** I put this

`<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>`

after the `<form>`

**2.** from system->configuration->web I put the `Cookie Lifetime` to `9600` or `96000` or `0` the `Cookie Path` and `Cookie Domain` i left it empty and i set the `Use HTTP Only` to `yes` or `no` , but the thing is whatever combination settings I do i still got redirected to the login page.

**3.** I checked the logs file, nothing relevant. I cleared the cache etc

**4.** I put this code:

```
if (!($formKey = $this->getRequest()->getParam('form_key', null)) || $formKey != Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()) {
    $this->getRequest()->setParams(array('form_key' =>Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()));
}
```

in my AccountController.php in the `loginPostAction` function, but it changed nothing.

After I clear my browser cache on chrome it works , but i logout and login in again i am redirected to login page. Any idea ??

**[update]** 
Im storing the session in db : `<session_save>db</session_save>`

Comment: I think multiple cookie domain are creating. Check the cookie domain from browser.

Comment: theoretically i shouldn't do any settings to my browser, I cannot tell to my customers to go to chrome ->settings -> do that or other things :) Thx for the understanding

Comment: I am just asking to check to you not customer and accordingly you can resolve it.

Comment: I have 2 cookies from google analytics like `mywebsite.de` and 3 others on `www.mywebsite.de` (`frontend`, `frontend_cid` and `Local_storage`)

Comment: if I remove the cookies from `www.mywebsite.de` i can login instantly

Comment: so put cookie domain ` mywebsite.de`  from suytem configuration. Clear your browser cookie and try.

Comment: I put the domain `mywebsite.de` on the store level, cuz I have multiple shops. that problem still persists :(

Comment: put it in website level as all stores share same domain in magento.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52582/discussion-between-attila-naghi-and-prasanta-hatui).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/86383)

Comment: Do you have any other ideas ? :D

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issue in you local machine.

Then change your base Url as

> http://localhost/magento/ to http://127.0.0.1/magento/

Comment: I'm on live :)  like `https://example.com`